# jQuery each doesn't work with certain classes, or classes in general?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, class, cordova

I'm using Phonegap to build a small (test only) Macrumors application, and remote hosts actually work (there is no same host browser restrictions). I am using the jQuery `Load()` function to load the contents of the Macrumors homepage http://www.macrumors.com/ into a bin, hidden div, then the each function to loop through all the article classes to show the title in a box  with a link to the page.

The problem is, after the Macrumors HTML content is loaded, the `each` function doesn't work with the article class. Also, in the load function (which allows you to specify certain selectors, id's and classes included, to only load in those sections of the page) the class doesn't work; none of the classes do, in both the load function and each function. And many Id's don't work in the `each` function either.

- Can anybody explain this to a noob like me?

Here is the code:

```
function onDeviceReady()
{
    // do your thing!
    $('#bin').load('http://www.macrumors.com/ #content');
    $('.article').each(function(){
    var title = $('a').html();
    $('#content').append('<b>'+title+'</b>')

    }); 
}
```

And the HTML stuff

```
    <body onload="onBodyLoad()">
       <div id="bin">
       </div>

       <div id="content">
       </div>

    </body>
```

I sincerely apologize if there's some very simple mistake here that I'm missing; I'm a **major** JS newbie.

Comment: Show us the HTML and the javascript.  We can only make wild guesses without seeing the actual code.

Comment: It would help if you posted the actual selector code

Comment: lol I like how 4 people said to post code :) oh btw, please post your code

Comment: code is now posted! should have done it originally, my bad

Comment: You should also post the html.  You can use http://jsfiddle.net/ to post the code, scripts, and any css.  That way you will get better support.

Comment: jsfiddel would be useless, as load doesnt work with external html files because of a browser restriction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.load()` is asychronous.  It hasn't completed yet when you're executing `.each()`.  You need to put your `.each()` and any other code that wants to operate on the results of the `.load()` in the success handler for `.load()`.

You would do that like this:

```
function onDeviceReady()
{
    // do your thing!
    $('#bin').load('http://www.macrumors.com/ #content', function() {
        $('.article').each(function(){
            var title = $('a').html();
            $('#content').append('<b>'+title+'</b>')
        }); 
    });
}
```

I'm also guessing that your `.each()` function isn't working quite right.  If you want to get the link out of each `.article` object, you would need your code to be like this so that you're only finding the `<a>` tag in each `.article` object, not all `<a>` tags in the whole document:

```
function onDeviceReady()
{
    // do your thing!
    $('#bin').load('http://www.macrumors.com/ #content', function() {
        $('.article').each(function(){
            var title = $(this).find('a').html();
            $('#content').append('<b>'+title+'</b>')
        }); 
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's all I needed to know

Comment: The ' #content' in the first parameter is significant, as it will return only the contents in '#content' from the requested URL during the parse.
jQuery parses the returned document to find the element with an ID of content. This element, along with its contents, is inserted into the element with an ID of result, and the rest of the retrieved document is discarded. (via [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/))

Comment: @ChrisN - thanks Chris.  That isn't something I knew about jQuery `.load()`.  Edited that out of my answer and put the space back.